# Does Laravel's 'regenerateSession' reset session time, so it is starting from zero again, or just generates a new token?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I wonder if 'regenerateSession'  starts over session time, or just new token is generated, leaving the elapsed session time as it was before.

According to every documentation only the renewal of token ID is mentioned, but no hint about whether the session time start over again from zero?

Comment: Elapsed session time is not something that is typically measured to begin with

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of a session lifetime concept. Session lifetime is a timer of idle behavior. For example if session lifetime is 60mins, then user can stay idle without any requests for 60 minutes. If during these 60 minutes request occures, then session timer restarts from that point. 

In your case the only time session()->regenerate() can be called is by users request, meaning session lifetime will be renewed anyway.

Comment: or more likely, if session lifetime is 120 then the session is valid from the time of the last request for 120 minutes. Its not like a countdown. Its like ignore this session after xx:xx, but reset the time on each request.